# Is there a way to schedule the downloads in Transmission BitTorrent Client?

Tags: transmission

I have added a couple of torrent files to Transmission BitTorrent Client to be downloaded.

I have a limited internet speed so I can't start all of them in a single go; so I have to peep in after every 30 minutes or so to start downloading other file(added to the client).

I don't want to peep in 30 minutes; looking for a way to schedule the downloads (i.e when one download completes other files can start automatically) without manual intervention.

Comment: ***Slightly off subject:***  I have experimented with third-party add-ons for Deluge BitTorrent client.  There is one that 'serializes', so that only one file (or as defined) can be streamed at once.  There is also ones for time scheduling jobs, and to support download windows (for Australian on/off peak rates).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you can accomplish this easily. Try the following steps:

1. Click Edit -> Preferences
2. Select Downloading tab
3. Set the Maximum active downloads number to 1, this should do the trick.

Comment: +1, but will the next download start automatically?

Comment: @Ankit Yes. You set this setting and then select all torrents. Click"Start" when all are highlited. One will start. The rest will be queued. IIRC you can use buttons to move torrents up and down the queue.

Comment: @ObesessiveFOSS, +1,  thanks this is very helpful. :)

Comment: You can also adjust the downloads activity timeout - see @Achu 's screen shot.  That should (theoretically - I haven't tried it) allow another torrent to start if the current one stalls out.  That way you can let things run even longer before needing to check on progress.

Answer (score 4):

`Edit` -> `Preference`  under download tab set `Set maximum active download` to `1`

[image]